# UIPopoverController missing side images in screenshot

Tags: ios, core-graphics, screenshot, draw, popover

I'm trying to take a screenshot of my interface and the code I'm using is missing the status bar and the sides of the UIPopoverController.  I hear it may be impossible to include the status bar (is this true?) but the sides of the UIPopoverController are what really concern me.  Here is the screenshot code:

```
// Create a graphics context with the target size
// On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
// On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Iterate over every window from back to front
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen]) {
        // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
        // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Center the context around the window's anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
        // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
        // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

        // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

        // Restore the context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}

// Retrieve the screenshot image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// rotate the image
double rotation = 0;
// rotate image based on orientation
switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        rotation = M_PI/2;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        rotation = -M_PI/2;
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        rotation = M_PI;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

//  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
// calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width, image.size.height)];
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

// Create the bitmap context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

//   // Rotate the image context
CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, rotation);

// Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-image.size.width / 2, -image.size.height / 2, image.size.width, image.size.height), [image CGImage]);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

Also I've created a [sample project](http://www.filedropper.com/popovertest) which demonstrates this.[image: Simulator Screenshot] [image: Screenshot Generated by Code]

Comment: Having the same problem. It seems to be an Apple native bug. This problem disappears when I use following code : `    CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen)` But UIGetScreenImage() is undocumented...so I cant use it... :( That would be great if we got any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to how UIPopoverController is presented. Its actually not a UIViewController, instead is in its own window. You need to update your drawing code to something more like:

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Iterate over every window from back to front
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
            // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            // Center the context around the window's anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
            // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
            CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
            // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                                  -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                                  -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

            // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
            [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

            // Restore the context
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested this, so give it a shot and let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: Oh sorry.. I must have been looking at a different question and wrote out the wrong code to the wrong question. Sorry about that. :)